# Predicate model that satisfies different formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider the formulas:

$$F_1:=\ \exists y (P(y)\wedge Q(y))$$
and
$$F_2:=\ \exists y\exists x \neg(\neg P(x)\rightarrow Q(y))$$

1. Provide a model that satisfies both formulae $F_1$ and $F_2$.
2. Provide a model that does not satisfy formula $F_1$ and also does not satisfy formula $F_2$.
3. Provide a model that satisfies formula $F_1$, but does not satsify $F_2$.
4. Provide a model that does not satisfy formula $F_1$, but does satsify $F_2$.

I don't quite understand how to find model satisfying the implication part in the second formula.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to rewrite $F_2$ avoiding implication, indeed $F_2$ is equivalent to $\exists x\exists y(\neg P(x) \wedge \neg Q(y))$, in this way the exercise becomes easier.

---

As $P$ and $Q$ are unary predicates, the interpretation of the formula $\exists y P(y)$ is simply "there exists an element in $P^I$" (where $P^I$ is the subset of the domain that interprets $P$), so it simply means that $P^I$ is not empty. In this way, the first formula says "the intersection between $P^I$ and $Q^I$ is not empty", while the second one says "there is an element outside of $P^I$ and another one outside of $Q^I$": now I think it's easy to give an answer to the problem.